# How can I decimate a mesh to remove unnecessary triangles?

Tags: modeling, mesh

I have the following mesh. As you can see there are quite a bit of triangles that are unnecessary, and can be reduced. However, if I use the decimate modifier, other triangles are also decimated and morphs the shape. 
[image]

Comment: The decimate modifier has a lot of options. Play with the settings for planar, using **Angle Limit** and **All boundaries** for more info read: https://www.blender.org/manual/modeling/modifiers/generate/decimate.html?highlight=decimate

Answer (score 8):

If decimate is too destructive, then while in *edit mode*, select all, then press <kbd>X</kbd>*>limited dissolve* to remove excess edges in your model. You can adjust the angle threshold in the operator panel as needed. Don't forget to also remove doubles with <kbd>W</kbd>*>remove doubles*.

[image]

You can also try *tris to quads*. Press <kbd>Spaebar</kbd> and type in *tris to quads*, and select the operation from the menu, or or press <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>J</kbd>