# Decimate and dissolve don't remove triangles!

Tags: mesh, obj

I can't lower triangle count in my obj I brought in from Daz 3D. Right now there's no textures. I tried multiple numbers on Decimate and limited dissolve. I tried everything on these two other pages:

[How can I decimate a mesh to remove unnecessary triangles?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/52942/how-can-i-decimate-a-mesh-to-remove-unnecessary-triangles)
[Removing triangles and ngons](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/84520/removing-triangles-and-ngons)

Why won't it lower triangles? I started with a little over 2 million triangles then It went down to 1.9 million but that's it.

UPDATE: Limited Dissolve is reducing triangle count, but only by a few thousand. I need something that will reduce a 2 million triangle model to 14K triangles. Any ideas?

Also, will eliminating triangles screw up my UV maps? I'm trying to remap my textures so they're all coming from one image after this for Tabletop Simulator but I've never worked with UV before so do you think the Daz textures will still fit?

Comment: Did you actually select the entire mesh when you do this?

Comment: Make sure all vertices are actually connected. Meshes imported from other softwares can be disconnected on import

Comment: @TheLabCat would highlighting all the objects in the layers panel and drawing a marquee around all the points select all of them, or do you have to do something more?

Comment: @Gorgious I wouldn't be surprised if they were disconnected, they came from separate products in Daz. What would I do about it if they were separated?

Comment: @Ikari layers panel? Where is that? Do you mean the Layout editor?

Comment: @TheLabCat I'm not sure what it's called. The area where all your objects and sub-objects are listed. I'm coming to Blender from Adobe so I'm still thinking in terms of Photoshop/Illustrator. If you click on an object in that list, does it select it, because when I did that and tied dissolve it didn't do anything. I had to click and drag a lasso over the points in the model instead. Kind of a drag. What if an object is hard to click on?

Comment: @Ikari oh, I see. Yeah, that is the Outliner. But selecting an object in the 3D viewport is usually easier. Once an object is selected, you must go into edit mode (if you can select individual vertices you are already here), and you can press A to select all. Alt+A in 2.80 up is select none.